# Intel NUC 11 (or newer) overheating

Tags: fan, cooling, overheating, intel-nuc

I have an intel NUC11TNHi7, overheating for no apparent reasons. CPU's temperature reaches 75++°C just on idle.

I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/1363932/655676) about NUC7 overheating but it appears that the [best answer](https://superuser.com/a/1363933/655676) (with full details on how to dust the fan) doesn't apply fully to my NUC11.

I also found a [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/intelnuc/comments/9ld4yo/comment/j2s1ooz/) which lead me to the fact that NUC11 or newer have an additional step to reach the fan but unfortunately doesn't explain how.

So, I wonder how to reach the NUC11 (or newer) fan in order to dust it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Mtl Dev](https://superuser.com/users/448836/mtl-dev) and to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EYp0YKpApE), I found the way to dust my NUC11 fan. The video is about a NUC12 but the steps described fully worked for me.

Solution (from Mtl Dev + additional steps for NUC11 or newer) :

1. Open the NUC, via the 4 screws at the bottom.
2. Remove ram/ssd, and all plugged wires. Be carefull with the two tiny black and white wires - take a photo first so you know where to plug the wires back in later.
3. Remove SATA cable if you have an additional hard drive.
4. Remove the extension bracket if you have one.
5. Remove the two screws holding the motherboard in on the NUC7.
6. Remove the top cover. Remove all the visible crews.
7. Carefully remove the mother board from the chassis.
8. On the back side of the motherboard, you will find the cooling fan and cooling fins/air intake. (These may look perfectly clean).
9. Unscrew the two screws holding the fan in, remove the fan's power cable and remove the fan.
10. You may find a big clump of dust inside - blow out the cooling fins and the fan.

CPU's temperature on idle dropped to 50++°C which is not perfect but far more sustainable than the previous 75++°C!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.